# iPhone multiple NSTimer problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am writing a multithreaded iphone application in which the socket operations take place at the backend. The front end is the user interface. My problem is that the NSTimer is working only at the front end. That too only one timer works on the frontend. Unable to implement NSTimers at the backend? Are there any threading issues involved? Can\t figure out what might be the problem.

Comment: Did you start a run loop on your "backend" thread?

Comment: Nope. Do I need to start one?